# Python 3 subprocess, how to read json file

Tags: json, python-3.x, linux, ssh, subprocess

I am trying to make a script that needs to be executed locally and connect to a remote server via SSH. So far, I believe the subprocess might do the trick, however, I am not able to open the JSON file that I need to parse.

First of all, I need to establish an SSH connection to the server by passing the Username/Server and port. I suspect the format will be something like that:

`(["ssh", "-p22", "{}@{}".format("user", host)])`

Once I'm connected to the server, I need to parse JSON located here:

`/var/log/access.json`

Is that possible to be achieved or I should switch to Bash for the particular script?

Thank you.

Comment: Consider using an SSH client library for Python like [Paramiko](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/stable/api/client.html).

Comment: You could `scp` the file and work on it locally. To run code on the server, you'd either have to first copy the code (e.g., script.py) and its dependencies to the server, to run it there, or include it all on the ssh command line, which could get messy. Subprocess doesn't matter here, if that process is still just running on the original machine.

Comment: Rather than rely on string formatting, I would use `['ssh', '-p22', '-u', 'user', host]`.

Answer (score 0):

Unless the file is absolutely huge, it would be simpler to just transfer the file to your local machine and parse it there.

```
d = json.loads(subprocess.check_output(['ssh', '-p22', '-u', 'user', host, 'cat /var/log/access.json']))
```